# Wowza: Vod Adaptive bit-rate Streaming issue in audio file

Tags: android, audio, stream, wowza, adaptive-bitrate

I am using Wowzastreamengine-4.0.3 For my application.
I have build wowza on the server. I have to adaptive bit-rate for 2g (or lower network connection).

I have set up all adaptive bitrate by following this link

http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?546-How-to-do-adaptive-bitrate-streaming

I have created different smile files for different bitrate, but non of them working correctly, As i have tested in 2g network through running application my android mobile. but it is not working perfectly, it stick on some point I cann't find what the problem there? please help me.thanks in advance

I mentioned below some smile file .all files in `wowzastreamengine/content/`folder

1

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <smil title="testing">
        <body>
            <switch>
                <audio src="mp3:54b11d4790db4b9f1a0adc4a.mp3" systemLanguage="hin">
                    <param name="audioBitrate" value="10000" valuetype="data"></param>
                </audio>
            </switch>
        </body>
    </smil>
```

2

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <smil title="MStream">
        <body>
            <switch>
                <audio src="54b11ce390db4b9f1a0adc47.mp3" systemLanguage="eng" audio-bitrate="48000">
                    <param name="audioBitrate" value="48000" valuetype="data"></param>
                </audio>
            </switch>
        </body>
    </smil>
```

3

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <smil title="Stream">
        <body>
            <switch>
                <video height="360" src="mp3:54b11d4790db4b9f1a0adc4a.mp3"
                    systemLanguage="eng" width="240" audio-bitrate="36000" system-bitrate="36000"/>
            </switch>
        </body>
    </smil>
```

4

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <smil title="testing">
        <body>
            <switch>
                <audio src="mp3:54b11d4790db4b9f1a0adc4a.mp3" systemLanguage="hin">
                    <param name="audioBitrate" value="10000" valuetype="data"></param>
                </audio>
            </switch>
        </body>
    </smil>
```

5

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <smil title="videotesting">
        <body>
            <switch>
                <video height="20" src="mp3:54b11d4790db4b9f1a0adc4a.mp3"
                    systemLanguage="eng" width="20" video-bitrate="10000" audio-bitrate="10000"/>
            </switch>
        </body>
    </smil>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally ,
I have to do encode mp3 file with myself and apply to wowza.
So I have encode one mp3 file through FFMPEG
I used some Linux command for convert mp3 to lower bit-rate for encode manually. 
And put this files in wowza content folder

`ffmpeg -i 54dd82e02a4eefbd0330aa95.mp3 -ab 128k 54dd82e02a4eefbd0330aa9548.mp3`

Note For installation `ffmpeg` in linux found here some link

http://wiki.razuna.com/display/ecp/FFmpeg+Installation+for+Ubuntu
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu